# Get JSON data from php to ArrayList of String android

Tags: java, android, json

I have built a php script who give me my JSON data of my mysql database, but in android studio I don't know how I can put my data in a ArrayList of String

I have tested many possibilities but no one works,

If you have any idea about my code it can be very good

```
ArrayList<String> ListeFamilles = new ArrayList<>(15);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.selectionneracteactivity);

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.26:8888/GetNomFamille.php");
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
            ListeFamille.add(line);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
```

JSON:

```
[{"Famille":"TEXT1"},{"Famille":"TEXT2"},{"Famille":"TEXT3"},{"Famille":"TEXT4"},{"Famille":"TEXT5"},{"Famille":"TEXT6"},{"Famille":"TEXT7"},{"Famille":"TEXT8"},{"Famille":"TEXT9"},{"Famille":"TEXT10"},{"Famille":"TEXT11"},{"Famille":"TEXT12"},{"Famille":"TEXT13"},{"Famille":"TEXT14"},{"Famille":"TEXT15"}]
```

PHP:

```
<?php
  mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
  mysql_select_db("mydb");
  $sql=mysql_query("SELECT Famille FROM FAMILLES");
  $rows = array();
  while($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        $rows[] = $r;
  }
  print json_encode($rows);
  mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: show the php, and the json ... you are not reading this properly if it is really json.

Comment: JSON format is wrong

Comment: thanks, i hae modify my php file and i have something like that

Comment: That wont deserialise nicely to an ArrayList ... you probably want your json output to look like ["TEXT1","TEXT2" , ... ]" .  Java side , dont roll your own json deserializer, there are plenty available to do that for you and produce the ArrayList. , i would typically use google's GSON library to decode this kind of stuff.

Comment: Thanks for that, but before trying to deserialize my JSON object, i need to download it but it doesn't work with my method, any idea ?

Comment: Your MySQL database is on your server, right? So your server should provide a REST API and then, in your app, you can use something like Retrofit 2 together with Gson to get the JSON from the server and automatically parse it to your ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

You should not do network connection in mainthread, Read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html#Avoiding) article and try to add it in asynctask,

For Json parsing after getting the value you can try this,

```
   StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    ArrayList<String> listOfValues = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result.toString());

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i);

            if(jsonObject == null) {
                continue;
            }

            String jsonValue = jsonObject.optString("Famille");

            listOfValues.add(jsonValue);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```